# ImportError: No module named 'mutiprocessing'

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to import 'multiprocessing' and using python 3.5.3 but its gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssser.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mutiprocessing
ImportError: No module named 'mutiprocessing'
```

when i try to install multiprocessing module then i again error occure
i am using following command for installation

```
python3 -m pip install multiprocessing
```

and got error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-26ilgzih/multiprocessing/setup.py", line 94
        print 'Macros:'
                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-26ilgzih/multiprocessing/
```

however when i import "import multiprocessing" in terminal then no error occure but when i used in my file "ssscr.py" then it gives error 
i am using geany,and python3 (IDEL) on raspberry pi3

Can any body help me how i can fix this error ?

Comment: Are you trying to use micropython? Regular distributions have ``multiprocessing`` bundled since Python 2.6.

Comment: Its just a typo, you wrote mutiprocessing but its multiprocessing

Comment: If it was really just about the typo, consider deleting the question, since it's unlikely to ever be helpful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are installing `multiprocessing` in the python 2 version. Could you use `pip3` to install the package?

```
pip3 install multiprocessing
```

Also use the following command to check which pip you are using

```
$ ls -l `which pip`
$ ls -l `which pip3`
```

And to see if the package got correctly installed or not use

```
$ pip show pip
$ pip3 show pip
```

**Update:**
multiprocessing is built-in after python2.6
 OP did a typo. It should be 
`import multiprocessing` in place of `import mutiprocessing`

Comment: when i try to install using **python3 -m pip3 install multiprocessing**
then i got error 
**/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3**
when i check pip3
$ ls -l `which pip3`
**-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 293 Feb 26  2018 /usr/bin/pip3**
what should i have to do?

Comment: can you try `pip3 install multiprocessing`

Comment: it gives same error which i have posted
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-s3j7r7gf/multiprocessing/setup.py", line 94
        print 'Macros:'
                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s3j7r7gf/multiprocessing/

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing/ python 3 has it  inbuilt, you don't need  to install it seperately.  You did a __typo__ import mutiprocessing. __l__  is missing

Comment: Thanks a lot 
'l' was missing. Now issue is resolved

Answer (score 10):

For others who faces Similar error like

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocessing';
```

would also occur if you name your python file as multiprocessing.(as it makes ambiguity between your program name and actual module name)
Just rename your file and it will work (if you have dependency installed).